# Is there a way to get the real viewport size in hardware-pixels without viewport meta tag?

Tags: javascript, hardware, device, viewport, pixel

I want to get the viewport width with javascript. But not the common virtual viewport. I need the logical hardware viewport and in my case it's not an option to set the viewport meta tag.

To clearify my issue: I want to get 320 pixels on IPhone 5 (640 hardware pixels with pixel ratio 2) though the virtual viewport is much more than 320 pixels.

Is there a way to do that?

thanks,
Helmut

Comment: If you don't set the viewport meta tag, then `screen.width` will always give you the available width on the device in device pixels, and if you set the viewport meta tag, it will still give you the exact same number. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: The problem with only screen.width would be, that it gives the whole screen width on desktop browsers. But I only want to get the browser width. But I just found a solution .. see below

Comment: Oh! I thought you were talking about Mobile devices only.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it to write .. was lost in my thoughts ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my Answer in this article: http://menacingcloud.com/?c=viewportScale

.. and breaked it down to the real essential things ..

.. so, this is my result:

```
// cross browser way to get the common viewport width:
var viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

// cross browser way to get the orientation:
var isLandscape = document.documentElement.clientWidth > document.documentElement.clientHeight;

// then get the logical screen width if the screen is smaller than the viewport
// otherwise get the viewport width
var screenWidth = screen.width < viewportWidth ? 
    Math[isLandscape ? 'max' : 'min'](screen.width, screen.height) :
    viewportWidth;

// screen width
console.log(screenWidth);
```

Here is a ready to use function for all of you

```
function getLogicalDeviceDimensions() {
    // cross browser way to get the common viewport width:
    var viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    var viewportHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

    // cross browser way to get the orientation:
    var isLandscape = document.documentElement.clientWidth > document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    // then get the logical screen size if the screen is smaller than the viewport
    // otherwise get the viewport size
    var screenWidth = screen.width < viewportWidth ?
            Math[isLandscape ? 'max' : 'min'](screen.width, screen.height) :
            viewportWidth;

    var screenHeight = screen.height < viewportHeight ?
            Math[isLandscape ? 'min' : 'max'](screen.width, screen.height) :
            viewportHeight;

    return [screenWidth, screenHeight];
}
```